# Change column date with time zone

Tags: postgresql, date, alter-table, timestamp-with-timezone

Short question! I have a column with a date (timestamp with time zone) and it looks like f.e.:
"1993-11-22 12:00:00+01"

I want to change the content of this column so that in the end I have:
"1993-11-22"

How can this easily be done?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are all the values in the same timezone? If they're not, which timezone do you want the date for?

Comment: I basically just want to delete the time.. The timezone in which the records are is not important..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the data type to be a date:

```
alter table TABLE alter COLUMN type date;
```

Comment: Is it automatically gonna drop the time, and keep the date without changing it?

Comment: yes. If you want a preview of what it will do run a query such

select COLUMN::date from TABLE